# Django strange queryset with Q objects

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset, django-q

I have a Django project that works with Django1.4 + MySQL. This project has to models - Book and Author.

```
class Author(models.Model):
   ...

class Book(models.Model):
   ...
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   ...
```

Book model has a foreign key to Author's model and title  CharField. I  receive title value and need to make a Book queryset taking in consideration that it should contain:

- books which title equal to requested title
- latest book for each author that doesn't have book with requested title

I was thinking to use django Q objects and try something like this:

```
Book.objects.filter(
    Q(title=requested_title) |
    Q(author__books__title__ne=requested_title))
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It will always give you all objects. It is equal to Book.objects.all() because you are making OR of book whose title doesn't match and books whose title  match. Where is the time field for querying latest book ?

Comment: @SachinGupta added date field to Book model. The thing is that I want to get not simply all the books, but the latest book for each author (it means that resulting queryset shouldn't contain books with the same author).

Comment: if the title matching book is not latest from it's author ? Can you give me the use case why you need such two different querysets as OR ?

Comment: @SachinGupta As you see I need otherwise book with the requested title or   title of author's latest book only for authors that don't have book with requested title.